# LevelDB value size

Tags: key-value-store, leveldb

I'm using LevelDB(scala bindings) to store large (k,v) pairs on disk. While the keys are usually short strings, the values can be in the 10s of MBs (an outlier could even in the 100s of MBs). It does not seem to be doing a good job of storing large values - my application runs into frequent full GCs and things get messy.

I dont see any limit on the value size in the documentation. Does anyone know of similar issues? Should I try breaking up my value into smaller chunks?

Comment: no limitation on value size, but benchmark is better for small size, and in our case, limit value size to 1MB, and usually under 10KB.

Comment: I second the previous comment, you need to include key and value size in your benchmarks.